# Covert 2D array to 1D array storing the 2D array position (col, row) and the value in a 1D array

Tags: java

I have managed to convert it to output the values from the 2D array, but have no idea how to get the position.

Here is my code:

```
public static int[] convert(int [][]twodarray)
{
    int[] onedarray = new int[twodarray.length * twodarray.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < twodarray.length; i ++)
    {
        for(int s = 0; s < twodarray.length; s ++)
        {
            onedarray[(i * twodarray.length) + s] = twodarray[i][s];
        }
    }
    return onedarray;
}

public static int [] printonedarray(int [] onedarray)
{
    System.out.print("onedarray: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < onedarray.length; i++) 
    {

            System.out.print(onedarray[i] + "\t");

    }
    System.out.println();
    return onedarray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your 2-d array is not a jagged array, than the original cordinates for `A[i]` should be `A[i/x][i%x]` where `x` is the original length of the least significant column your 2/d array

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am not really sure if I get you correclty. But I understand it this way: 
You have a 2 dim. array and want to convert it to a 1 dim. array. 
Therefore you want to ready the first coloumn and the first line. 
Then you want to add this value at the forst position of the 1 dim. array. 
Then you read the next row and want to add this value and so on. 
If I am right I suggest an arrayList for your 1 dim array. Because you don't know how deep the coloumns are. And ArrayLists are dynamic. You can simply add an element and don't need to give a position.
Your code suggestion was pretty good and I just converted it to an ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class test
    {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> convert(int [][]twodarray)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> onedarray = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
        for(int i = 0; i < twodarray.length; i ++)
        {
            for(int s = 0; s < twodarray[i].length; s ++)
            {
                onedarray.add(twodarray[i][s]);
            }
        }
        return onedarray;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> printonedarray(ArrayList<Integer> onedarray)
    {
        System.out.print("onedarray: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < onedarray.size(); i++) 
        {

                System.out.print(onedarray.get(i) + "\t");

        }
        System.out.println();
        return onedarray;
    }
}
```

If I missed your question I am sorry for a "wrong" answer. 
I hope it will help you!